# BindingGroup CancelEdit does not work with UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem seems to be simple, but I don't find one way to solve this. So, I'm here.

Here is my code.

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="nome" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:IsNotNull/>
                <ValidationRules:MyStringLengthValidationRule Length="45"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I'm using bindgroup for commit and cancel my edit. But, when I use `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`, the command `BindingGroup.CancelEdit()` does not work. Why?

I can't remove `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` because with this the `ValidationRules` work when the text was changed.

Comment: Please paste the text of the code into your question. Nobody wants to squint at a blurry screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake.

Comment: Much better, thank you. It's a little rough on my iPhone with the extra indenting but I'll take a look when I get to the office.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "does not work"? Very, very specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Validation rules are applied when the target value (`TextBox.Text` in this case) is assigned to the source (the viewmodel property in this case). `BindingGroup.CancelEdit()` clears error state and copies the source values to the target properties.

When you set `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` on that `TextBox.Text` `Binding`, on each keystroke in the textbox the `Binding` runs validation on `TextBox.Text`, and if it passes validation, it copies the target value to the source property. That means it copies `TextBox.Text` to `yourViewModel.nome`.

For example, say `yourViewModel.nome` is initially null.

User clicks in the text box and types "Arnold". `yourViewModel.nome` is updated six times while the user is typing, once for each character.

The user clicks the `Cancel` button, which causes `BindingGroup.CancelEdit()` to be called.

`BindingGroup.CancelEdit()`, behaving as designed, copies the *current* value of `yourViewModel.nome`, the string `"Arnold"`, to `TextBox.Text`.

That's the problem you're seeing.

With `BindingGroup`, validation *is* commit. If a field is validated and passes validation, it's committed. And once you commit, it's too late to cancel.

If you want to hold off validation and validate/commit a group of fields together, then you use a `BindingGroup` and `UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"`, which causes validation/commit to happen only on `BindingGroup.CommitEdit()`, or when you call `UpdateSource() on the`Binding` itself:

```
myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

## Lecture Ends, Answer Begins

**If you want to validate without commit, you're going to have to do something a little different.**

The simplest and most straightforward thing to do is set `UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"` on your bindings, and handle `TextChanged` on the text boxes:

XAML

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper" TextChanged="anyValidatedTextBox_TextChanged">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="nome" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:IsNotNull/>
                <ValidationRules:MyStringLengthValidationRule Length="45"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Codebehind

```
private void anyValidatedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox)
        .GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
        .ValidateWithoutUpdate();
}
```

Or you can make the entire `BindingGroup` validate without update:

```
private void anyValidatedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    myFormStackPanel.BindingGroup.ValidateWithoutUpdate();
}
```

## Another Answer

A more generalized way of doing this, which is more orthodox MVVM, is to write a behavior that does the same thing.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace HollowEarth.Behaviors
{
    public static class Validation
    {
        #region Validation.OnPropertyChanged Attached Property
        public static DependencyProperty GetOnPropertyChanged(FrameworkElement obj)
        {
            return (DependencyProperty)obj.GetValue(OnPropertyChangedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetOnPropertyChanged(FrameworkElement obj, DependencyProperty value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(OnPropertyChangedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OnPropertyChangedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("OnPropertyChanged", typeof(DependencyProperty), typeof(Validation),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged));

        private static void OnPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = d as FrameworkElement;

            if (e.OldValue != null)
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor.
                    FromProperty(e.OldValue as DependencyProperty, obj.GetType())
                    .RemoveValueChanged(obj, ValidateHandler);
            }

            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor.
                    FromProperty(e.NewValue as DependencyProperty, obj.GetType())
                    .AddValueChanged(obj, ValidateHandler);
            }
        }

        static void ValidateHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            var dprop = GetOnPropertyChanged(fe);
            fe.GetBindingExpression(dprop).ValidateWithoutUpdate();
        }
        #endregion Validation.OnPropertyChanged Attached Property
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox 
    xmlns:hb="clr-namespace:HollowEarth.Behaviors"
    CharacterCasing="Upper" 
    hb:Validation.OnPropertyChanged="{x:Static TextBox.TextProperty}"
    >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="nome" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:IsNotNull/>
                <ValidationRules:MyStringLengthValidationRule Length="45"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I'd rather have that behavior applied to `BindingGroup` or the `BindingGroup`'s owner rather than to individual fields, but when I tried that, `BindingGroup.BindingExpressions` and `BindingGroup.Items` were both empty at the time it was applied. `BindingGroup` has no events and its collections have no events. I bet you could do something with a behavior on the `BindingGroup` owner where you hook things up on `LayoutUpdated`, but my attention is starting to wander. I'll leave that as an exercise for the student.

As a further exercise, you could just copy and paste my code without even reading it. That's what I do, nine times out of ten.

Comment: Awesome dude. Besides you solve, you taught me. Thank you for everything! How can I help you?

About "I bet you could do something with a behavior on the BindingGroup owner where you hook things up on LayoutUpdated". I don't have any idea how to do this :(

Comment: @StanleyIPC I messed with it a little, and it turned out to be easy to do badly, but not at all easy to do well. If you need help getting started doing it, don't even think of going there. What I've got above is enough: If you put `hb:Validation.OnPropertyChanged="{x:Static TextBox.TextProperty}"` on all the text boxes in your binding group, it'll do what you want. Or you could even just go ahead and use the TextChanged event idea I suggested first. Either one will work and neither breaks MVVM.